# Apache POI XLS: add new row on top

Tags: apache-poi

Can you help me, how to add a new row to the HSSFSheet? The trick is that I want to add a new row at the top the XLS document.

Here is my code so far:

```
  HSSFSheet sheet = doc.getSheetAt(0);
  HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
  row.createCell(0).setCellValue("----newRow---");
```

Suppose I have a document with lines:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

The code above gives me result:

```
----newRow---
line2
line3
```

instead of

```
----newRow---
line1
line2
line3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First Shift all the rows one place down, this will create a new row at the start using following:-

```
sheet.shiftRows(startRow, endRow, n);
```

i.e.

```
sheet.shiftRows(0, sheet.getLastRowNum(), 1);
```

and now you have first row available for writing anything.

**Definition:-**

> Shifts rows between startRow and endRow n number of rows. If you use a
>   negative number, it will shift rows up. Code ensures that rows don't
>   wrap around. Calls shiftRows(startRow, endRow, n, false, false);
>   Additionally shifts merged regions that are completely defined in
>   these rows (ie. merged 2 cells on a row to be shifted).
>
> Parameters:
>
> startRow the row to start shifting
>
> endRow the row to end shifting n the number of rows to shift